# getting Error while trying to log in to maximo 7.6

Tags: websphere-8, maximo

I have deployed MAXIMO7.6 on WAS8.5.5.3 but am receiving the following error:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [MTContextFilter]:
Could not find required filter class -
psdi.webclient.system.filter.MTContextFilter.class
```

while trying to log in. Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem persist over restarts? It is a common problem in earlier versions that starting Maximo too soon after deploying causes "missing class" problems that go away with restarting the JVM / MXServer.

Comment: yes the error still exists after a restart . i have tried restarting BOTH and the i am still having the same issue

Comment: Have you checked in the file system for that class file?